# MATLAB heat map

Tags: matlab, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map using MATLAB, but the default function in MATLAB program doesn't any sense to me.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/heatmap.html

Is there anyone who can help me with labeling first, so that I can read through the other function myself after that? Or is there any other program which will have a more user-friendly interface?

```
HeatMap(Data, ...'RowLabels', RowLabelsValue, ...)
```

I have a data set of a `81*2` matrix and my label is a `81*1` cell for x-axis and `1*2` for y-axis. Now I can successfully import the excel data and plot the data using a heat map, but I have a hard time fill in the variable in the HeatMap function.

Thanks so much.

Comment: HeatMap gets Data which is a matrix. If I understand you correctly, you have only the (x,y) matrix coordinates. try first to build a matrix from your x-y coordinates.

Comment: Do you mean you want a heatmap that has been clustered?

Answer (score 27):

HeatMap isn't actually standard function for this, it comes from the Bioinformatics Toolbox. The simple way of drawing a heatmap might be like:

```
 A = 1:50;          % matrix to draw
 colormap('hot');   % set colormap
 imagesc(A);        % draw image and scale colormap to values range
 colorbar;          % show color scale
```

As @natan suggested, you might want to build your matrix first and then draw using `image` or `imagesc`. Also you migt want to see article on my blog which shows that [some color sets are better for accessibility than others](https://dotnetbattlefield.taurit.pl/matlab-heatmap-colormap/), e.g. for printing in grayscale or in color vision deficiency.

Comment: Simple and elegant, lovely!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish, but I think you might want to use [colormap{}](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html).  If you're trying to create a classic "[heatmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map)", then colormap is the function you want. Basically, if you've got x,y position, and a Z value that you want to represent as a color, this is the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Plotly MATLAB](https://plot.ly/api/matlab) API to make a heatmap. Try this:

```
r = plotly({struct('z',randn(50,50), 'type','heatmap')}) % => https://plot.ly/~matlab_example/18dos(['open ', r.url])
```

[image: this heatmap]

You can see the interactive version and installation [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plotly-graphs).

Disclosure, I am on the Plotly team.

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB [contourf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html) command may by useful to you.