# MATLAB -- How does one plot a heatmap from nxn matrix?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a 50x50 matrix with some numbers ranging from 0 to a bit over 1. How do I show a heatmap of this data with a colorbar? What I'm looking for is a plot where the `x` and `y` values range from `1` to `50` and `1` to `50`, with each point (`x`, `y`) given a color corresponding to the size of the data at the matrix entry (`x`, `y`). For an example of such a heatmap, check out [this amusing xkcd post](http://xkcd.com/1138/).

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24253-customizable-heat-maps

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What do you think about this example? [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851352/matlab-heat-map)?

```
>> A = randi([10,60],100,100);
>> colormap('hot')
>> imagesc(A)
>> colorbar
```

[image]