# Creating hexagonal plot

Tags: matlab

So, I have this excel file which looks like this (9 - empty, other numbers - data):

```
 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 9
 9 9 9 9 9 9 2 3 1 1 1 1 3 2 9
 9 9 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 9
 9 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 9
 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 9
 9 9 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 9
 9 2 3 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 1 1 3 2 9
 9 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 9 9
 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 9 9 9
 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 9 9 9 9
 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 9 9 9 9 9
 9 2 3 1 1 1 1 3 2 9 9 9 9 9 9
 9 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

And I have to create a plot which would look somehow like this (something like heat map):

[image: heat map]
<sub>(source: [b-inet.com](http://b-inet.com/intellect/technology/nuclear-reactor/index_files/image011.gif))</sub>

I need to do it for my thesis. Problem is, that I am no programmer. But I was told, that best tool for this is Matlab (although I am  sure, that there are other tools). Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: I don't see any connection between your data and the expected output, but drawing a heatmap is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676363/matlab-how-does-one-plot-a-heatmap-from-nxn-matrix

Comment: We can only guess how the plot is supposed to look. Should it by any chance look [like this](http://i.imgur.com/DoZcYx8.png)?

Comment: @Mathias Thanks for response. And yes, how did you achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

First: Rearrange your Excel calculation to provide a better formatted Matrix. Then use this Matlab/[Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html) code:

```
d=[9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9;
9,9,9,9,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,9,9,9,9;
9,9,9,2,3,1,1,1,1,3,2,9,9,9,9;
9,9,9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,9,9;
9,9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,9,9;
9,9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,9;
9,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,9,9;
9,2,3,1,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,1,3,2,9;
9,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,9,9;
9,9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,9;
9,9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,9,9;
9,9,9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,9,9;
9,9,9,2,3,1,1,1,1,3,2,9,9,9,9;
9,9,9,9,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,9,9,9,9;
9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]'

figure; hold on
s=size(d);
for i = 1:s(1)
    for j=1:s(2)
        if d(i,j)!=9
            scatter(i+mod(j,2)/2,j, 40, d(i,j), 'filled');
        end
    end
end
colormap('hot');
axis equal;
```

The `colormap('hot')` command produces the colors in this plot. Read up on the colormap command if you want different colors.