# openCV: Plotting a colormap from a matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, plot

I have a 50 x 50 matrix having certain values  from 1 to 50. I need to plot a color map for the same using OpenCV .

I have already done this in MATLAB (with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676363/matlab-how-does-one-plot-a-heatmap-from-nxn-matrix)):

```
>> A = randi([10,60],100,100);
>> colormap('hot')
>> imagesc(A)
>> colorbar
```

And the output comes like [image: this].

I would like to do the same  using openCV.

How do I proceed for this ?

I am unable to understand  how do I implement the function of "hot"  which appears like this (see only hot)

[image: like this]:

Additionally I would also be interested in putting a color bar as shown in the first image.

---

**Update (Final code I am running)**

Unfortunately still I am unable to plot the correct color map: Here is the MATLAB code:

Note : A is a 10 by 100 matrix.

A=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ;
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;
    ]

colormap('hot'); 
 imagesc(A)
  colorbar

And here is the output:

[image]

Now I created a text file with same data, and my text file looks like this:

[image]

And used the following code to achieve the same result as of MATLAB:

```
   int main() 


{




ifstream Read("myfile.txt");

vector<int> nums;
while ( !Read.eof() ) {
    int n;
    Read >> n;
    nums.push_back(n);
}
// now make a Mat from the vector:
Mat mat(nums);

cout<<mat<<endl; //for testing 


Mat mat1d(nums);
Mat mat2d = mat1d.reshape(1, 10);
//
Mat image; //create an empty image. (you can leave it empty ;)
//// Apply the colormap, but on the 2d mat, not on the 2d vector, please:
applyColorMap( mat2d, image, COLORMAP_JET );
            // Show the result:
imshow("colormap", image);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

But the output from the above is meaningless.

I need to match the results from MATLAB and Opencv.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html

Comment: the code you show, seems totally unrelated to your question.

Comment: @berak Thanks for the link. Yes my approach was wrong. I though I will try to modify this code for 2d thermal plot.

Comment: @berak BTW can you have look at [my another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967900/how-to-read-write-from-to-using-opencv-from-a-text-file)

Comment: @berak Kindly see my update section above. I want to apply color map on a matrix , rather than an image.

Comment: how many numbers are in your txt file ? is this a 1d or a 2d Mat ?

Comment: @berak its a 2D Mat. two rows with "123456"

Comment: do you know the width and height ? are there exactly width*height items in your txtfile ?

Comment: @berak. This is a test application, so I just put 123456 in two rows. So the width is 6, and height is 2. In actual application I will have 50 x 50 values.

Comment: @berak I changed the image  size to 10 x 10. Kindly see the update 2 above. The window called colormap is coming very thin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to reshape the 1d vector, to a 2d mat :

```
    //
    // before doing anything else, CLEAN UP YOUR DAMN TXTFILE. 
    // it should contain nothing than numbers and spaces.
    ifstream Read("m.txt");

    // be extra picky about the type here.
    // we are reading in a 8bit grayscale map.
    vector<uchar> nums;
    for (int i=0; (i<100*10)&&(!Read.eof()); i++ ) {
        int n;
        Read >> n;
        nums.push_back(n);
    }

    // now make a Mat from the vector:
    Mat mat1d(nums);
    Mat mat2d = mat1d.reshape(1, 10);

    // your data is in the [0..9] range, so scale up to [0..255] uchar range
    mat2d *= (255/10); 

    cout<<mat2d<<endl; //for testing 
    //
    Mat image; //create an empty image. (you can leave it empty ;)
    //// Apply the colormap, but on the 2d mat, not on the 2d vector, please:
    applyColorMap( mat2d, image, COLORMAP_HOT );
                // Show the result:
    imshow("colormap", image);
    waitKey(0);
```

[image]

Comment: 1 element(channel), 10 rows, please [see here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape)

Comment: unfortunately, it did not work even now. Kindly see my update above.

Comment: what was the content of your text file? same as the screenshot above under update?