# Opencv: Unable to correctly read/write from/to using OpenCV from a text file?

Tags: c++, opencv

System info:  windows 7, 32 bit, opencv 2.4.10, msvs 2010

I have a text file having some integer values. 
I want to read these values in a Mat object m, and then print out on the console.

What I tried so far is this:

```
int main()
 {

Mat m;
/// read:
 FileStorage fs("myfile.txt",FileStorage::READ);

if (!fs.isOpened()) {std::cout << "unable to open file storage!" << std::endl; return 0;}

fs["mat1"] >> m;

cout << "mat1 = "<< endl << " "  << m << endl << endl;



return 0;

}
```

However  this prints ;

> mat1 =  []

the actual data in the file is:

```
123456
123456
```

So kindly help me understand what is wrong here.

**Update**
I even tried mytext.xml by simply renaming the .text file. But still I see empty matrix as the out above.

Oh so  the file is not opening as the output is:

> unable to open file storage!

Comment: 1. please show a few lines of your txtfile. 2. check fs.isOpened() to see if it really found the file.

Comment: @berak 1-the content in the file:first and second line is 123456. 2- Yes, the file is not opening. "unable to open file storage!" I updated the code

Comment: again, it cannot read arbitrary txt files. it needs to be either xml or yml . please [rtfm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html)

Answer (score 1):

the [FileStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html)  cannot read arbitrary txt files. it needs to be either xml or yml. so, if you want to read it in that way, you better save it that way before, too.

```
Mat m = ...;
/// write:
FileStorage fs("myfile.txt",FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "mat1" << m;
fs.release(); // flush
```

---

if all you have is a txt file, try a different approach:

(this assumes integers !)

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream in("my.txt");
vector<int> nums;
while ( !in.eof() ) {
    int n;
    in >> n;
    nums.push_back(n);
}
// now make a Mat from the vector:
Mat mat(nums);
```

Comment: in the first code snippet , do you want to say myfile.xml?

Comment: if you name it 'xml', it will get formatted as xml, in *any other* case as yml.

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that `FileStorage` is opening the file, then check that when calling this function

```
fs["mat1"] >> m;
```

`mat1` is the name of variable saved in the `.yml` or `.xml` file.