# Is there something like MATLAB's colorbar for OpenCV?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm writing a C++ app using the OpenCV 3.0 library. I'm playing with the colormap feature, but I'd like to add a colorbar (see example below from MATLAB) to the image window. Even if it's on the side/external, this way the user has an idea of the range. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

[image: Colorbar Example from MATLAB]

Comment: this /may/ help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966580/opencv-plotting-a-colormap-from-a-matrix

Comment: Thanks, that's actually where I started. Unfortunetly, they don't mention how to generate the colorbar, just how to make the plot. I'm trying to add the actual "color bar" on the right of the example figure above showing the relationship between color and value.

Answer (score 1):

[See here the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r037E.png)

```
cv::Mat out;
color_map(input_image, out, cv::COLORMAP_JET);
```

//Function to Draw a color map

```
void color_map(cv::Mat& input /*CV_32FC1*/, cv::Mat& dest, int color_map){

  int num_bar_w=30;
  int color_bar_w=10;
  int vline=10;

  cv::Mat win_mat(cv::Size(input.cols+num_bar_w+num_bar_w+vline, input.rows), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));

  //Input image to
  double Min, Max;
  cv::minMaxLoc(input, &Min, &Max);
  int max_int=ceil(Max);

  std::cout<<" Min "<< Min<<" Max "<< Max<<std::endl;

  input.convertTo(input,CV_8UC3,255.0/(Max-Min),-255.0*Min/(Max-Min));
  input.convertTo(input, CV_8UC3);

  cv::Mat M;
  cv::applyColorMap(input, M, color_map);

  M.copyTo(win_mat(cv::Rect(  0, 0, input.cols, input.rows)));

  //Scale
  cv::Mat num_window(cv::Size(num_bar_w, input.rows), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
  for(int i=0; i<=max_int; i++){
      int j=i*input.rows/max_int;
      cv::putText(num_window, std::to_string(i), cv::Point(5, num_window.rows-j-5),cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6 , cv::Scalar(0,0,0), 1 , 2 , false);
  }

  //color bar
  cv::Mat color_bar(cv::Size(color_bar_w, input.rows), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
  cv::Mat cb;
  for(int i=0; i<color_bar.rows; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<color_bar_w; j++){
      int v=255-255*i/color_bar.rows;
      color_bar.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)=cv::Vec3b(v,v,v);
    }
  }

  color_bar.convertTo(color_bar, CV_8UC3);
  cv::applyColorMap(color_bar, cb, color_map);
  num_window.copyTo(win_mat(cv::Rect(input.cols+vline+color_bar_w, 0, num_bar_w, input.rows)));
  cb.copyTo(win_mat(cv::Rect(input.cols+vline, 0, color_bar_w, input.rows)));
  dest=win_mat.clone();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to draw the bar on the right separately, this might work for you:

```
/*Aim:- Generate a 20x255 colorbar starting at point (200,50)*/
int b=0,g=255,r=255;//start at yellow
int y=50;//start at y=50, then increment
while(g>0)//run till green color reaches 0
{
  b++;
  g--;
  r--;//gradually convert yellow to blue
  y++;
  Scalar color=Scalar(b,g,r);
  rectangle(img,Point(200,y),Point(220,y+1),color,1);
}
```

Let me know if this gives the expected result