# How to show 2-D matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

[image]

Hi guys,
I want to show a 2-D array in matlab like the picture below,but I dont know what should i search for.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should be clearer about what is your real objective, and what you want to do with the 2D array. also you talk about "2D array like the picture", but you can get really a lot of data from that image, so please specify which informations you actually want

Comment: I mean , how can I show the value of a 2-D array like this? red stands for high value and blue is low value , here 2-D array is voting matrix in image Processing

Comment: I think you are looking for a heat map of the data, which is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676363/matlab-how-does-one-plot-a-heatmap-from-nxn-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the spectogram plotting, which is basically a surf map:

```
figure
surf(Y0, 'edgecolor', 'none'); view(0,90); axis tight;
```

Where Y0 is your Matrix (Assuming the value in the matrix is Magnitude).

You may also use the Spectrogram plotting tool, check out [spectrogram](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html)

I might also add, that in some cases, use log(abs(Y0)), the log magnitude is particularly good at showing results where the overall data is not sparse.

Comment: You are welcome, please remember to accept as correct answer if you are ready to accept it.